# Not getting Active Directory details after hosting

Tags: c#, iis-7, active-directory

I wrote C# code to get email from Active Directory. It is working fine on my local system, but after hosting I am not getting email address. Followings are the things I already tried -

1. Changed application pool identity to `NetworkService`
2. Enabled Windows and Digest Authentications (both at the same time and one by one too)

Code:

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "comppany.com" , "DC=compnay,DC=com", ContextOptions.Negotiate))
// tried above and below//(ContextType.Domain, System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName))
{
                // validate the credentials
                bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(Uid, Pwd);

                if (isValid)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, Uid))
                        {
                            return up != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(up.EmailAddress) ? up.EmailAddress : string.Empty;
                        }
                        //return "Validate successfully.";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        return ex.Message;
                    }
                }
}
```

Also tried following -

```
using (var connection = new DirectoryEntry())
{
      using (var search = new DirectorySearcher(connection)
      {
         Filter = "(samaccountname=" + Uid + ")",
          PropertiesToLoad = { "mail" },
       })
       {
         return (string)search.FindOne().Properties["mail"][0];
       }
}
```

None of them are working after hosting the app in IIS7.0

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try debugging it remotely? Or logging?

Answer (score 0):

It will be because your user (i.e. you) will have rights to read from Active Directory, but the IIS user and Network Service won't.

Put a try catch round the using statement thing and you should see this in the exception.

There are alternative PrincipalContext constructors that allow you to specify the details of the user to connect as, or you could change the IIS app pool to run as a user with rights - I'd go with the PrincipalContext way though.

As a quick test try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341016%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) version of the PrincipalContext constructor - put your username and password in the username and password paramemetrs and see if it works when hosted in IIS - if this works then you need to come up with some way of passing the user details in via config. (Generally a service account with only the rights to read, whose password does not change often is used for this)